# How to display the text of one tableview cell in the detailtextlabel of previous controller through array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have created a  controller class named TAddAlarmController which has a  tableview which consists of 6 rows. When I click on the second row it navigates to a page which is a new controller name TAlarmNewController which is a tableviewcontroller and in which I have created a nsmutablearray and populated that array with 7 static values so when the second controller is displayed the tableview is displayed with 7 static values in it.

I want that when I click on any row of second controller the value that is present inside the cell of the paticular row should be set to detailtextlabel of the previouscontroller i.e TAddAlarmController.

This is my code:

This is AddAlarmcontroller.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class StopSnoozeAppDelegate;
    @class Alarm;
    @class TAlarmNewController;
    @interface TAddAlarmController : UITableViewController {

        StopSnoozeAppDelegate *app;
        IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
        NSUndoManager *undoManager;
        Alarm *am;
        TAlarmNewController *anew;
    }
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    @property (nonatomic,retain)Alarm *am;
    @property (nonatomic,retain)NSUndoManager *undoManager;
    @end
```

This is my .m file

```
    #import "TAddAlarmController.h"

    #import "Alarm.h"
    #import "TAlarmNewController.h"


    @implementation TAddAlarmController
    @synthesize dateFormatter;
    @synthesize am;
    @synthesize undoManager;



    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark View lifecycle




    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        // Release any properties that are loaded in viewDidLoad or can be recreated lazily.
        self.dateFormatter = nil;
    }


    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    }


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 6;
    }


    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 44;
    }




    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        /*
         Dequeue or create and then configure a table cell for each attribute of the book.
         */
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            //cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }


        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0: 
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Time";
                break;
            case 1: 
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Repeat";
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Sound";
                break;

            case 3:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Snooze Interval";
                break;

            case 4:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Alarm Message";
                break;

            case 5:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Snooze Penalty";
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }




    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {




        TAlarmNewController *controller = [[TAlarmNewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TAlarmNewController" bundle:nil];

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                controller.editedObject = @"Time";

                break;
            case 1:

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
                [controller release];

            default:
                break;
        }

     }




    - (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {    
        if (dateFormatter == nil) {
            dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            //[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
        }
        return dateFormatter;
    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
    }


    @end
```

This is TAlarmNewController.h

```
    @class TAddAlarmController;

    @interface TAlarmNewController : UITableViewController {
        IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
        UIDatePicker *datePicker;
        id editedObject;


            TAddAlarmController *Addalarm;


        NSMutableArray *days;//this is the array where i am storing 7 values statically

    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) id editedObject;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *days;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) TAddAlarmController *Addalarm;
    -(IBAction)cancel;
    -(IBAction)save;
    @end
```

This is my .m file

```
    #import "TAlarmNewController.h"

    #import "TAddAlarmController.h"


    @implementation TAlarmNewController

    @synthesize  editedObject,datePicker, tblView,days,Addalarm;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark View lifecycle


    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        UIBarButtonItem * saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
        [saveButton release];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
        [cancelButton release];

        days =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Every Monday",@"Every Tuesday",@"Every Wednesday",@"Every Thursday",@"Every Friday",@"Every Saturday",@"Every Sunday0",nil];

        [super viewDidLoad];


    }


    - (TAddAlarmController *)Addalarm {
        if (Addalarm == nil) {
            Addalarm = [[TAddAlarmController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        }
        return Addalarm;
    }



    -(IBAction)save{

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //
    }

    -(IBAction)cancel{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }



    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [days count];
    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell;
    }





    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    }




    - (void)dealloc {
        [datePicker release];

        [super dealloc];
    }


    @end
```

Comment: People are more likely to read code if you post only the relevant snippets and not the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FirstViewController

1, keep a member variable(NSString) named detailTextValueFromSecondController.

2, create a function named

```
-(void)refreshTableToSetDetailText:(NSString *)detailTextValue
```

Then in your SecondViewController

Inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

place the following code:

```
for (int i =0; i < [[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]; i++)
            {
                UIViewController *aController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i];

                if ([aController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
                {
                   FirstViewController *aFirstViewController = (FirstViewController *)aController;
                   [aFirstViewController refreshTableToSetDetailText:yourstringtosetondetaillabel];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:aController animated:YES];
                }

     }
```

Comment: in the function refreshTableToSetDetailText nothing should be written

Comment: the stringtosetondetaillabel should be set depending on the indexpath of the selected row and the value in it

Comment: hi @Adarsh i have done code but when i run application and click on the cell on the second controller my app crashes and gives me error that [TAddAlarmController refreshTableToSetDetailText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b57f50'

Comment: That is something basic. I thought you will be able to write that method your self. You should reload you table in that method. And in configure cell method you should place the yourstringtosetondetaillabel to your cell.

Comment: when i select any of the row in the second view controller it does not gets back to the first view controller and not displays the values in the detailtextlabel.Please help me yaar

Comment: sent me your project to adarsh_vc@yahoo.co.in

Comment: i cant sent bcoz in my off mails are blocked

Comment: I just edited and aadded my a line of code please check and let me know it that works.

Comment: @Rani let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1694/discussion-between-adarsh-v-c-and-rani)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , find out which row was chosen by the user, and store that value in `NSUserDefaults` for a specific integer key for communicating between views.

```
NSUserDefaults *chosenrow = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[chosenrow setInteger:99 forKey: StringYouWantToDisplay];
```

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of the previous controller, get the key for the integer

```
NSInteger myInt = [chosenrow integerForKey:StringYouWantToDisplay];
```

And check if it is 99. If this is the case then you can be certain that that particular value was chosen, and allocate the `detailedTextLabel` for the cells.

Somethings to note:

1. Make sure to `reloadData`for your tableView in your `ViewWillAppear` or you cannot see the changes for the `detailedText`
2. Set the value of the chosen row in a `NSString` property of the second class. Make sure to reference that class in the the previous view so that you are able to grab the value from that `NSString`.
3. `NSUserDefaults` is for communicating between two views. Check for NSUserDefaults if a row was chosen. If a row was not chosen, then you need not allocate a detailedTextLabel. On the otherhand, if a row was selected, you will need to allocate it..

Comment: NSUserDefaults *chosenrow = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[chosenrow setInteger:99 forKey: StringYouWantToDisplay] this code should be written in did select method of my second controller

Comment: i have 7 string values that should be set on the tableview cell not integer so how to set string value in the nsuserdefaults